# "<?" not being rendered as PHP

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I just inherited a code base from a previous developer and am in the process of getting things setup in my local LAMP vagrant box.

For some reason, the php code that is wrapped in `<?` is not being rendered. It renders code in `<?php` fine.

Is there a php.ini setting I need to adjust to enable the shorthand php declaration support?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 | PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Comment: There is, but you just replace them with `<?php` better

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately, that is not an option. This is a large code base and I am making some minor adjustments to it. I don't want to make a major update like that.

Comment: @ATLChris using short tags is not a good practice & not recommended, as some PHP versions may treat it as deprecated (though PHP 5.5.x is fine with that). In short, do not use short tags.

Comment: @Raptor No version treats them as deprecated, that is completely false and you should stop spreading that. They are *not* deprecated and they have never been deprecated. *At best* their use is discouraged, for the dubious reason that they *might* not be enabled on every server.

Comment: I don't use them. They were used in this code I inherited to make a few minor changes to.

Comment: @meagar my bad, but PHP 5.3 disabled it with intention, as it confuses with XML header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your php.ini file, specifically [short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).